# Сводить концы с концами

Tags: фразеология

О человеке, который живет бедно, говорят, что он едва сводит конца с концами (как я его понимаю!))). Но как-то раньше я никогда не задумывался над прямым смыслом этой поговорки. А действительно, какие концы с какими концами надо сводить, чтобы жить в достатке? То есть, о чем изначально говорилось в этой поговорке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта поговорка не обязательно русского происхождения, напр. она с 17 века известна в Англии (to make ends meet) и Франции (joindre les deux bouts de l’an); есть аналогичная польская (zwiazac koniec z koncem). Есть несколько толкований происхождения (связывание верёвок для крепления мачт, чтобы корабль шёл дальше; схождение застёжек на концах ремня, сведение бюджета). Наиболее основательные доводы приводятся в пользу "бюджетной" версии, где речь идёт всего о двух "концах", соотв. английскому варианту 'to make both ends meet'. Речь идёт о сходимости конечных записей доходов и расходов (например, в конце года). Поначалу эта версия вызывала скептицизм из-за слова 'meet', которое (в современном понимании) в лучшем случае могло указать на "встречу" записей расходной книги (совпадение по длине). Но в толковом словаре 16 века нашли его старое значение (to agree, to match - согласоваться, совпадать) - поэтому речь могла идти о совпадении доходов и расходов по цифрам.

http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-mak1.htm

http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=24711

Answer (score 0):

.."палка о двух концах: и туда, и сюда. всякая вещь о двух концах" (В.Даль)

Это и о том, что концы хоронить (прятать) следует, например, в плетении чего-либо (корзин, ковров), и о том, что в каждом деле одна работа подхватывается следующей, стыкуется с предыдущей, а в иной ситуации - работы по времени связаны своими окончаниями и результатами. И то и другое не несёт в себе непременную беду, но представляет большой труд.

Концы с концами умело сводятся. Заметьте, - число множественное!